# Baye's Rule in Cryptography

Tags: cryptography, bayesian, bayes-theorem

In "The Theory that Would Not Die", McGrayne states that Baye's rule was used to crack codes in Cryptography.  Is there some simple explanation for this?  If not, is there a textbook that explains it concisely?

Comment: Could this possibly be referring to https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1740-9713.2010.00424.x

Answer (score 1):

One source is [Edward Simpson: Bayes at Bletchley Park (pdf)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1740-9713.2010.00424.x/pdf). If you google "bayes rule bletchley" you will find others.